# Huawei HMS MLLocalTextAnalyzer with Transactor returns no results from camera stream (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin.android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have integrated HMS MLkit into my Xamarin.Android mobile app project, following steps from https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201466917572130070 (sections "Xamarin ML Kit Setup Process" & "Xamarin App Development"). I then proceeded to make an Activity class that uses LensEngine and MLAnalyzer APIs to detect text within camera stream. This looks more or less like this:

```
MLLocalTextSetting textSetting = new MLLocalTextSetting.Factory().SetLanguage("en").SetOCRMode(MLLocalTextSetting.OcrTrackingMode).Create();
             
var analyzer = MLAnalyzerFactory.Instance.GetLocalTextAnalyzer(textSetting);
 
analyzer.SetTransactor(new OcrDetector());
 
_cameraEngine = new LensEngine.Creator(ApplicationContext, analyzer)
           .SetLensType(LensEngine.BackLens)
           .ApplyDisplayDimension(1280, 720)
           .ApplyFps(6.0f)
           .EnableAutomaticFocus(true)
           .Create();
```

The OcrDetector class for now looks like this:

```
public class OcrDetector : Java.Lang.Object, MLAnalyzer.IMLTransactor
{
        public OcrDetector()
        {
        }
 
        public void Destroy()
        {
        }
         
        public void TransactResult(MLAnalyzer.Result results)
        {
            SparseArray objectSparseArray = results.AnalyseList;
            AnalyzeDetections(objectSparseArray);
        }
         
        public void AnalyzeDetections(SparseArray detectedItems)
        {
            // TODO:
        }
}
```

The camera seems to run smoothly, however, I don't get any results from the text analyzer (TransactResult never gets called). During the streaming, the console repeatedly throws an exception that looks like this:

```
02-23 12:02:57.154 E/LensAnalyzerRunable(15027): Exception thrown from receiver.
02-23 12:02:57.154 E/LensAnalyzerRunable(15027): java.lang.NullPointerException: *t*e*p* *o*i*v*k* *i*t*a* *e*h*d*'*n*r*i*.*t*l*S*a*s*A*r*y*c*m*h*a*e*.*m*.*l*d*.*e*t*i*t*r*a*.*l*e*t*N*t*v*T*x*A*a*y*e*.*n*l*s*(*o*.*u*w*i*h*s*m*s*k*c*m*o*.*L*r*m*)* *n*a*n*l* *b*e*t*r*f*r*n*e
02-23 12:02:57.154 E/LensAnalyzerRunable(15027):     at com.huawei.hms.mlsdk.text.MLTextAnalyzer.analyseFrame(MLTextAnalyzer.java:3)
02-23 12:02:57.154 E/LensAnalyzerRunable(15027):     at com.huawei.hms.mlsdk.common.MLAnalyzer.obtainPicture(MLAnalyzer.java:124)
02-23 12:02:57.154 E/LensAnalyzerRunable(15027):     at com.huawei.hms.mlsdk.common.LensEngine$LensAnalyzerRunable.run(LensEngine.java:39)
02-23 12:02:57.154 E/LensAnalyzerRunable(15027):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
02-23 12:02:57.157 E/HaLogProvider(15027): forbiddenHiLog openHa = false
02-23 12:02:57.158 E/HaLogProvider(15027): forbiddenHiLog.getVenderCountry=UNKNOWN
02-23 12:02:57.158 E/HaLogProvider(15027): forbiddenHiLog openHa = false
```

I have no idea what this NullPointerException means.
When I use different kind of analyzer, like this:

```
MLObjectAnalyzerSetting setting = new MLObjectAnalyzerSetting.Factory().SetAnalyzerType(MLObjectAnalyzerSetting.TypeVideo)
            .AllowMultiResults()
            .AllowClassification()
            .Create();
             
var objanalyzer = MLAnalyzerFactory.Instance.GetLocalObjectAnalyzer(setting);
```

Things work ok (that is, TransactResult gets called and I get no exceptions in the console, although this kind of analyzer isn't useful for my case).

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some recommendations to try to solve the issue:

1. In the code, change the synchronize call MLTextAnalyzer.analyseFrame() as show up in the error stack trace to asynchronize call, see sample code in the following document code section [ML Kit-Text Recognition (huawei.com)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/text-recognations-0000001051807680).

> Task task = this.analyzer.AnalyseFrameAsync(frame);
>
> ```
> await task;
>
> if (task.IsCompleted && task.Result != null)
>
> {
>
>     // Analyze success.
>     var result = task.Result;
> }
> else
> {
>     // Analyze failure.
> }
> ```

2. Make sure to use the latest Xamarin ML Plugin 2.0.5.300 (2020-12-31).  This upgrade has some enhancement of reduced the delay of recognizing English and other languages.
3. Refer to the following Xamarin sample code for HMS ML Kit integration [ML Kit-Xamarin Sample Code (huawei.com).](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Examples-V1/xamarin-sample-code-0000001053630353-V1)

Comment: Thank you Zinna. I have been told by Huawei developer support that the way I tried to do things (LensEngine + analyzer synchronous approach) is not supported by Xamarin plugin with local text analyzer. Therefore I will have to capture individual frames and analyze them as you suggested.

Comment: Hi Barti90, glad my answer in a way helped. If you have questions, you can always post them here under huawei-mobile-service or huawei-developer tag. I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

> ````
> MLLocalTextSetting.Factory().SetLanguage("en").SetOCRMode(MLLocalTextSetting.OcrTrackingMode).Create();
>               var analyzer = MLAnalyzerFactory.Instance.GetLocalTextAnalyzer(textSetting); ```
> ````

Try change your code into following

```
 var  analyzer = new MLTextAnalyzer.Factory(this)
                .SetLanguage("en")
                .SetLocalOCRMode(MLLocalTextSetting.OCR_TRACKING_MODE)
                .Create();
```

Hope it will help. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shirley. Unfortunately, the solution you suggested is for Java project, not C#-based Xamarin plugin.

Comment: You are advised to use the MLTextAnalyzer.Factory(context) parser. For details, see [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-References-V1/mltextanalyzer-factory-0000001052991643-V1?ha_source=hms1).